# Etsy: Retrieving transactions via the Api

Tags: c#, etsy

I'm using V2 of the Etsy Api. I know my consumer key and build up of my token is all fine because when I make a request for listings related to a receipt, I receive all details:

$"https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/receipts/{receipt.receipt_id}/listings?";

I then try to obtain all transactions for a listing:

$"https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/{lineItem.listing_id}/transactions?";

this call never returns and it doesn't error. As far as I can tell, I've built the call correctly.

After the build up of the call which includes all the OAUth stuff, If I paste the whole url directly in a browser, data is sent back to the browser.

So this is the build up of the call to Etsy:

I have a generic method

```
public async Task<T> MakeGetCallToEtsy<T>(string requestUrl)
    {

        var client = new OAuthRequest
        {
            Method = "GET",
            Type = OAuthRequestType.ProtectedResource,
            SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
            ConsumerKey = _consumerKey,
            ConsumerSecret = _consumerSecret,
            Token = _token,
            TokenSecret = _tokenSeret,
            RequestUrl = requestUrl
        };

        var url = requestUrl + client.GetAuthorizationQuery();
        var result = await url.GetStringAsync();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result);
    }
```

And this is my call to the method:

```
string requestUrl = $"https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/{lineItem.listing_id}/transactions?";

var transactions =  await _etsyComms.MakeGetCallToEtsy<EtsyTransaction>(requestUrl);
```

I thought the issue might be with the deserialization, but placing a breakpoint there, again it never gets to that point.

Has anybody come across this issue before, or can see anything I've missed in my build up to the call.

Comment: do we get to see any code? -- "or can see anything I've missed in my build up to the call." All we can see is that you didnt write anything

Comment: @pm100....I've expanded my question.

Comment: a) no exceptions being thrown? b) what do you see if you use fiddler c) did yuo try with postman

Comment: @pm100 using postman returns the expected data.